# Use the same Mathematica Executable Script on Different Computers

Tags: scripting, command-line

The first line in a Mathematica executable script specifies the directory of WolframScript, e.g.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/WolframScript -script
```

Assume I want to run a Mathematica executable script on two different computers, with different directories of WolframScript.
This means running the script on the first computer requires the first line to be e.g.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/WolframScript -script
```

while on the other computer the first line needs to be (say)

```
#!/usr/opt/mathematica/bin/WolframScript -script
```

How can I write the Mathematica exectubale script so that it runs on both computers without changing the first line?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not on Unix but Windows but you should be able to do this.  Booting up mac to test.

```
#!/usr/bin/env WolframScript
```